# Package creation provider not work after publishing on Packagist.org

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I create a package for remote auth token based, In package creation i register package namespace into root `composer.json` file and package work.when package development is complete i publish package on `packagist.org` . then i install package in new `laravel` application and put provider in `app.php` then run composer dumpautoload  i get this error any help me

```
In ProviderRepository.php line 208:

  Class 'Support\RemoteAuth\JSRServiceProvider' not found
```

[image]

composer json of package is

```
{
    "name": "support/remote-auth",
    "description": "api authentication libarary",
    "type": "library",
    "license": "MTT",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "ravi bhanderi",
            "email": "ravibhanderi14@gmail.com"
        }
    ],
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "require": {}
}
```

Comment: Is that class coming from your own code? Then please share the `composer.json` and directory structure from your package

Comment: @NicoHaase okay added

Comment: Have a look at the autoload section for composer at https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#autoload - how should the filepath for your provider be detected if you do not provide any help?

Comment: okay, Thanks probleam is solve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the autoload section for composer at [getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#autoload](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#autoload) - how should the filepath for your provider be detected if you do not provide any help